# glibc: Is there a way to get the used configure command line options?

Tags: glibc, configure

I want to update the distribution version of `glibc` and in order to keep the distribution settings, paths, ... I need the original used `configure` command line options.

Running `gcc -v` displays under `Configured with:` the `configure` command line options.

Is there something similar for `glibc`?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish. It seems likely you really want to do something else than finding out the configure options of glibc. You'll have to provide a bit more context.

Comment: @PerJohansson OK. I got you. Now it is updated. I hope it is clear...

Answer (score 2):

Unlike GCC, GLIBC doesn't record its `configure` options anywhere, so the direct answer is no.

However, if you download the source package for your current version of glibc and build it (precise commands vary between distributions), then you'll know how your current version has been configured.

P.S. Upgrading GLIBC incorrectly is one of the easiest ways to render your system unbootable. Make sure you have a suitable system recovery disk, and know how to use it before attempting this upgrade.

Comment: @unbootable: yes, I was once very close to this situation but I could revert it without a recovery disk. Upvote for the tip regarding the source package. I will check it out.